# I get the "Failed to connect to the host via ssh" error when Ansible tries to connect to a machine via ssh using private key

Tags: ansible

**I am trying to provision a machine using ansible. I must connect to it via ssh using a private key, instead of password.**

This is the content of my inventory.txt file:

```
target ansible_host=<ip_address> ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/<private_key_name>.pem
```

This is the content of my playbook.yaml file:

```
-
  name: Playbook name
  hosts: target
  tasks:
   <task_list>
```

When I am executing the command `ansible-playbook <playbook_name>.yaml -i inventory.txt` I get the following error:

```
fatal: [target]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", "unreachable": true}
```

I also tried executing the following command: `ansible-playbook <playbook_name>.yaml --private-key=~/.ssh/<private_key_name>.pem -i inventory.txt`, without the `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` property inside the `inventory.txt` file.

**Note: I can connect to the machine using the command** `ssh -i <private_key_name>.pem <username>@<ip_address>`.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are connecting as different user. In the above example you use `<user>@<host>` during ssh checks but you don't have `ansible_user=...` field configured. Try providing username this way in hosts file.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I omitted the ansible_user property. Thank you.

Comment: If that is the answer - please mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sure thing. But I need to wait a few minutes until I am able to do that.